# Transparent texture makes the mesh transparent too

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, eevee-render-engine

[image: The transparent part making a hole in his face]

Hi and thank you!
So I applied the skin textures on the body, then on edit mode selected the face area and applied a transparent PSD file with only eyes/mouth being opaque. We see them but the transparent area of the texture leaves a hole in his face... is there a way to fix this? Thank you!

I use Eevee and set alpha clip as a blending mode in texture settings.

Thank you!

Comment: read through the following link to understand how to work with transparency in a texture: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: Thank you Susu! I've read it before but couldn't find a solution. My model is textured using a colorramp with two colors. If I apply the texture like it says on the link, the color appears off, like he's wearing a skin mask. I'm trying different combinations to get the transparent face over the colorramp texture so it blends seamlessly.

Comment: The key concept is not to think in terms of transparency. If your image has an alpha channel use that as a mask to mix other elements. The color ramp texture should not be affected, what you want is to add the color of the eyes on top of the color of such ramp.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've figured it out!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gfxw7wP-Abfq6Yt1Q1vaNRy3ZqmBjxof/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer:
[image]

Thank you to Susu and Rob Proctor for the help! :)

Answer (score -1):

There could be a better way, but I don't think you can have multiple materials per face. You'll probably either have to duplicate the face mesh and then give each their own material or maybe or create a material that utilizes the skin texture and face combined.

Comment: I see, in that case, I guess I should duplicate the face mesh. Applying the combined skin texture with face won't allow me to get the look I want unfortunately.
Thanks a lot Rob! :)